# get the smallest items from a listOfLists group by keys

Tags: python

I've got a list like

```
listOfLists = [['key2', 1], ['key1', 2], ['key2', 2], ['key1', 1]]
```

The first item of an inner list is the key. The second item of an inner list is the value.

I want to get an output `[['key1', 1], ['key2', 1]]` which gives the list that its value is the smallest of the lists that has the same key and the output group by the key (my English is poor so just use the concept of Sql Syntax)

I've written some code like this:

```
listOfLists = [['key2', 1], ['key1', 2], ['key2', 2], ['key1', 1]]
listOfLists.sort()    #this will sort by key, and then ascending by value
output = []
for index, l in enumerate(listOfLists):
    if index == 0:
        output.append(l)
    if l[0] == listOfLists[index - 1][0]:
        #has the same key, and the value is larger, discard
        continue
    else:
        output.append(l)
```

this seems not smart enough
is there any simpler way to do this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using a dictionary (no need to sort the data)?

```
>>> listOfLists = [['key2', 1], ['key1', 2], ['key2', 2], ['key1', 1]]
>>> d = {}
>>> for k,v in listOfLists:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

>>> d = {k:min(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> d
{'key2': 1, 'key1': 1}
```

You can convert to a list if you want

Comment: Good answer - +1. Alternately you could use [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to simplify a little bit more :-)

Comment: @SeanVieira I don't like to use defaultdict for simple cases because it may confuse beginners by not raising `KeyError` when used as a normal dict... But, of course, the syntax is better

Comment: the solution is good but python2.6 doesn't support dictionary comprehensions

Answer (score 3):

## O(N log N) solution

You can just use the dict constructor for this. It is O(N log N) because of the sorting step

```
>>> dict(sorted(listOfLists, reverse=True))
{'key2': 1, 'key1': 1}
```

To see why this works, look at the result of sorted

```
>>> sorted(listOfLists, reverse=True)
[['key2', 2], ['key2', 1], ['key1', 2], ['key1', 1]]
```

The `dict` constructor will replace each key as it traverses the list and `sorted` has pushed the minimum for each key to the end of the sublist for that key

## O(N) solution

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for k, v in listOfLists:
...  d[k] = min(d.get(k, v), v)
... 
>>> d
{'key2': 1, 'key1': 1}
```

Comment: You can avoid one dictionary lookup with `d[k] = min(d.get(k, inf), v)` where `inf = float('inf')`. But it would probably be less readable (and would not work for things other then numbers).

Comment: @JBernardo, Good idea. `min(d.get(k, v), v)` works perfectly well too

Answer (score 2):

The [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module has a very useful [`groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function that is probably *exactly* what you need:

```
from itertools import groupby

listOfLists.sort()

for key, subgroup in groupby(listOfLists, lambda item: item[0]):
    print key, min(subgroup)
```